# Google charts and tweepy - real time data

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-visualization, tweepy

I've got a google chart set up (geo chart) and a Tweepy live streaming script that fetches coordinates of tweets in North America in real time. Is it easier to visualize this with the raw coordinates or should I be storing the data as JSON and trying to convert to GeoJSON? How can I have this so the chart gets updated fairly quickly?(~3s)? I'm using Django as my back end. I plan to have a user enter a tag which the script searches for and plots the locations of the tag.